# Dynamically load search results Rails

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax, search

I want to implement a simple search form and upon search form submit, I want to refresh a particular div and not the whole page.

here is what I have now.

In home_controller/_search.html.erb

```
<div class="search-form right">
    <%= form_for :anything, url: "tourism_packages/search", remote: true, id: 'search-form' do |form| %>
      <div class="search-fields">
        <%= form.label 'From' %>
        <%= form.select :starting_point, ['Chennai', 'Delhi'] %>
      </div>

      <div class="search-fields">
        <%= form.label 'To' %>
        <%= form.select :end_point, ['Mumbai', 'Pune'] %>
      </div>

      <div class="search-fields">
        <%= form.label 'Start Date' %>
        <%= form.date_field :start_date %>
      </div>

      <div>
        <%= form.submit 'Search', class: 'action-btn', id: 'search-btn', remote: true %>
      </div>
    <% end  %>

</div>
```

In home_controller.js

```
document.addEventListener("turbolinks:load", function() {
$('#search-form').submit(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $.post("/tourism_packages/search?");
    return false;
})
```

})

In my_controller.rb

```
def search_packages
  @packages = TourismPackage.search(params.require(:anything).
            permit(:starting_point, :end_point, :start_date))

  # render layout: false
      respond_to do |format|
    format.js       
  end
end
```

In my_controller/views/search_packages.js.erb

```
$("#search-result").html("<%= escape_javascript(render partial: 'search-result', locals: { packages: @packages } ) %>");
```

What actually happens is,

When I do a form submit, Only rails form submit is happening. The jquery .submit event is not fired. Only upon page refresh the jquery is being executed. As per my research, adding turbolinks event listener should solve this issue. But even after adding it, the problem persists.

Also point out any other mistakes in my code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are the things you need to change

Form Tag ID is not setting. So add html attribute to the form tag.

Also put the button outside of the form and handle button event separately

```
  <div class="search-form right">
    <%= form_for :anything, url: "tourism_packages/search", html: { id: 'search-form' }, remote: true do |form| %>
      <div class="search-fields">
        <%= form.label 'From' %>
        <%= form.select :starting_point, ['Chennai', 'Delhi'] %>
      </div>

      <div class="search-fields">
        <%= form.label 'To' %>
        <%= form.select :end_point, ['Mumbai', 'Pune'] %>
      </div>

      <div class="search-fields">
        <%= form.label 'Start Date' %>
        <%= form.date_field :start_date %>
      </div>


    <% end  %>

       <div>
        <%= button_tag "Search", data: { disable_with: "Please wait..." }, remote: true, class: 'submit' %>
      </div>
```

Your javscript code

```
$('.submit').on('click', function(){
         $('#search-form').submit();
      });
```

Comment: I did not notice that the form is missing the 'id' attribute. Thank you for pointing that out.